# Why can't download video title when to set proxy argument with youtube-dl?

Tags: video, proxy, title, youtube-dl

The command can get video title without `proxy` argument,run on my vps.

```
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znmQ7oMiQrM&list=PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9&index=1"
youtube-dl -o "/tmp/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --write-auto-sub --yes-playlist  $url
```

The output info for above command.

```
[info] Writing video subtitles to: /tmp/Session 1 - Introduction to Valuation.en.vtt
[download] Destination: /tmp/Session 1 - Introduction to Valuation.mp4
```

It can get video subtitles,now to add `proxy` argument,run on my local pc.

```
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znmQ7oMiQrM&list=PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9&index=1"
youtube-dl -o "/tmp/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/" --write-auto-sub --yes-playlist  $url
```

I only add `proxy` argument, keep all other unchanged,it get the following output:

```
WARNING: Unable to extract video title
[youtube] znmQ7oMiQrM: Looking for automatic captions
[info] Writing video subtitles to: /tmp/_.en.vtt
[download] Destination: /tmp/_.f248.webm
```

It can download video without title as the downloaded video,Whe the action is different for the argument `proxy` ,why to run on my vps do matter?
To add a `v` argument to show all info in detail.

```
youtube-dl -v --write-pages  -o "/tmp/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/" --write-auto-sub --yes-playlist  $url
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', '--write-pages', '-o', '/tmp/%(title)s.%(ext)s', '--proxy', 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/', '--write-auto-sub', '--yes-playlist', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znmQ7oMiQrM&list=PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9&index=1']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2019.07.16
[debug] Python version 3.5.3 (CPython) - Linux-4.9.0-9-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.9
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 3.2.14-1, ffprobe 3.2.14-1
[debug] Proxy map: {'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/', 'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/'}
[youtube:playlist] Downloading playlist PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9 - add --no-playlist to just download video znmQ7oMiQrM
[youtube:playlist] PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9: Downloading webpage
[youtube:playlist] Saving request to PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9_https_-_www.youtube.com_playlistlist=PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9_disable_polymer=true.dump
[download] Downloading playlist: Valuation
[youtube:playlist] playlist Valuation: Downloading 25 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 25
[youtube] znmQ7oMiQrM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Saving request to znmQ7oMiQrM_https_-_www.youtube.com_watchhas_verified=1_bpctr=9999999999_v=znmQ7oMiQrM_disable_polymer=true_hl=en_gl=US.dump
[youtube] znmQ7oMiQrM: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] Saving request to znmQ7oMiQrM_https_-_www.youtube.com_get_video_infohl=en_gl=US_video_id=znmQ7oMiQrM_disable_polymer=true_eurl=_ps=default_el=embedded.dump
WARNING: Unable to extract video title
[youtube] znmQ7oMiQrM: Looking for automatic captions
[debug] Default format spec: bestvideo+bestaudio/best
[info] Writing video subtitles to: /tmp/_.en.vtt
[debug] Invoking downloader on 'https://r4---sn-a5msen7l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1565674517&ei=tPdRXZy-MND8kgbJ7JrwCQ&ip=65.49.218.106&id=o-APXnQrHHHHttAI0VI1FjI3xIZNQKXoAcTffCZvbDaowF&itag=248&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-a5msen7l%2Csn-a5mekne7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=20&initcwndbps=1261250&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=123038403&dur=974.431&lmt=1540749282657199&mt=1565652704&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgWW_UbLJqGcCIkKNgYhCKSWEDpC_ND_4c-_e9LSbAMkACIQDKZNf_b01YjtrNllZFNq_dL7GX5bX6CM5jsgiaqw0JZQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIgFkroUYnazUgzoaBbuU1Ot4vu81LmQex7WfJoNhsNx6kCIQCCIeMh_wo0F2bUysi0P9yJCZBh9g9XfxKQpZMGvYKw6A%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes'
[download] Destination: /tmp/_.f248.webm
```

Comment: Why is it important to involve a proxy? Simply, if it breaks things, don't use it...

Comment: Please run it with `-v` first for `verbose` mode, should show you what is happening. Next you can add `--write-pages` this will write the files it download while processing your requests. It could happen that you get redirected to a country specific site and `youtube-dl` is not able to pic the title from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [update](https://github.com/Lamieur/youtube-dl/commit/5eabe9c3dc3fe05b26a7f3f833fb55b0287abd4a#diff-bd8242a0122c5207531954b67e6e51f0) to [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/) was recently made to address [similar issues](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/21934); try the new version:

```
$ youtube-dl --update
$ youtube-dl --version
2019.08.13
```

> If that doesn't resolve your problem you could try the [geo-restriction
>   options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#geo-restriction), or [file a bug report](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues) with the developers and
>   provide access to your vpn, vps, proxy, etc. so they can debug it.

↳ see: [How can I speed up my issue?](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#how-can-i-speed-up-work-on-my-issue)

Answer (score 2):

sudo pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl